# Importing vs linking to Excel spreadsheets

Tags: performance, excel, ms-access, import, hyperlink

I currently link to half a dozen Excel spreadsheets, mainly because it's easier/nicer for the users to edit the data in Excel (they've never used Access), and also any changes are reflected immediately, including if a new column is added which is then ready for use by queries straight away.

But is there a performance penalty for linking instead of importing this data? Some of my queries are slow, 1-2 minutes, and sometimes it can take 2-3 minutes just to SAVE a query. How would I set up Access to import a fresh version of these sheets each time the database is opened, and is it worth it?

Comment: This isn't really a good **multi-user** setup, you don't really want users to be able to amend the structures e.g adding/removing columns. I'm not sure of your background/knowledge level within access but I would favour storing all tables in access and developing the front-end screens for your users to interface with the data, is this an option for you?

Comment: For the size of the system and how it will be used it's not worth developing front end screens. I think if I can set up a macro to import the spreadsheets each time the database is opened, and lock down the spreadsheets so that only I could add extra columns, that would be a good balance.

Comment: But am I redudcing performance much by linking to a spreadsheet rather than having the data sit in an Access table?

Comment: Have you tested the performance of imported spreadsheets?  My gut reaction is that it will be much faster depending on the size of the spreadsheets.  This would be worth looking at.

Comment: @TonyWilkes Importing the spreadsheets to Access isn't certain to improve performance, as long as the spreadsheets are structured correctly like a database table, don't contain too much data, and aren't on a shared space with slow access times. Then they should provide suitable performance. However, if any of the queries would benefit from **Indexing** some columns then you would indeed have to import as I don't think you can set indexes against linked spreadsheets.

Comment: Copy/pasted the linked tables as local tables, and there is no slowdown at all - slowest query is about 10 seconds, even using 3 levels of subqueries, and saving takes maximum 5 seconds. So local tables are the way to go. I'll need to work out some importing macro that runs whenever the database is opened - either using importing specs (which unfortunately can't be edited) or a macro TransferSpreadsheet action. Thanks for the tips, be lucky, and remember that you can look at the stars without being in the gutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 factors that immediately come to mind regarding performance of linked spreadsheets:

1. Network performance
2. Number of spreadsheet links (you stated about 6)
3. Complexity of queries
4. Size of dataset (guessing that if people regularly edit it, likely well under 10,000 rows)

Given that saving queries is often slow, my guess is #1 is your primary bottleneck.  Yes there is a small performance hit for using links rather than importing, but your use case (small data set, not too many links) would make this penalty very small.  A slow network, on the other hand, will slow down every operation, including saving changes to the Access database itself.

Comment: I copied all the files onto my C drive, and reset the links to use the C: versions of the excel files, and the delays are still there, so I don't think it's #1. I don't think #2 or #4 are a problem, but with #3 I tend to build up multiple levels of queries - i.e. I'll have some base queries that access the linked tables direct, and then a few queries that refer to these base queries, and then some more complex queries that refer to these 2nd level queries. Is this 'not best practice'? Given that queries cannot be indexed, would this be where the slowdown could occur?

Comment: According to what you just said here, #3 + the fact that you are not able to index your data are obvious reasons for low performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put the solution I ended up with, as it pretty much solved the problems I had above, including automagically updating the data:

Have proper Access tables for use with queries, e.g. tblStoreDetails, tblPromotions

Still use spreadsheets to maintain the data, as this is the most flexible way of updating/viewing these things without building forms/a front end in Access, which wouldn't really be worth the time as no-one else will be using the database directly.

Link to these tables within Access, e.g. excelStoreDetails, excelPromotions

Set up an Autoexec macro that runs on startup (assuming the enable macros button is clicked) with a Delete query to empty the Access tables, and an Append query to add the rows from the linked Excel tables to the Access tables.

This gets around the problems caused by deleting/reimporting tables, mainly that they all end up in the Unassigned Objects group; or trying to use the import specifications and ending up with type mismatches.

Comment: But the drawback, which I'm only just finding now with some of the larger tables, is that the append query from the linked spreadsheet can be very slow, and the size of the database on the disk is now huge. Could factor in an automatic Compact & Repair on closedown, but that will add more time. Sigh, if Access was a horse someone would have shot it by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an excel file through an ADODB connection and open it in an ADODB.recordset. It's very very fast. In fact it can be as fast as a connection to a 'real' database.

The possibility to implement such a solution will depend on your ability to 'translate' your queries into recordsets. You'll need some good knowledge of VBA and ADODB objects, as myou will have to write the code for generating the recordset and then displaying their content on the screen (or in a report).

Comment: Over my head and underneath too - maybe in a couple of years.  8-)

Comment: Just one question: have you ever tried to use the embedded 'Import from Excel' tool available in Access? Give a try to your queries once the data is properly imported and indexed. If you see there's a big difference, you could then think about automating your import from Excel. It's not that complex, as you can just combine the VBA import function with a file multiselect box.

Comment: I've tried to automate using transferspreadsheet and runsavedimportexport in an Access macro, but the problem I'm having is that Access is deciding that some of the fields are integers, even though there are text values further down, and the field it's putting the data into is already set to text. Annoying, but don't think there's much I can do about this other than put a dummy row in the spreadsheet, which I really don't want to do.

Comment: I forgot this one. I guess we could solve this issue by creating the tables structures in the access file prior to first import. Anyway, in order to make use of indexes, we will need to keep the table structures stable between imports. But my aim here was to evaluate the difference between queries based on access data versus the same queries based on excel\linked data.

Comment: That's fine, I can work it out from here. But the thing is that, even if a table is set up prior to an import, with all the fields set to text, and the import spec says 'import these fields as text', Access will still have a look at the import file and try to guess what data it holds - and if it guesses wrong then there are import errors and missing data. 8-/